# The cube with side 2 is cut from the corner of rectangular prism with dimensions 4×3×5. What is the total surface area of the new object?

Tags: area, surfaces

I am not sure how much of the cube's surface area to take off from the total surface area. I know subtracting the entire surface area of the cube doesn't work, so I tried subtracting the 3 sides on the edges. Is this correct?

Comment: You've subtracted off the three removed faces, but you now have three new faces created by removing the cube. So you should account for this in your calculations.

Comment: @S.Ong- So how exactly would you calculate it then? What would the dimensions of the figure be?

Comment: Can you envision what the new object would look like? One hint: the areas of the newly exposed sides should match with the corresponding faces of the removed portion.

Comment: @S.Ong- I still am not clear what you do once you subtract the 12 from the total surface area..

Comment: Can you draw out what the object looks like in 3D?

Comment: You cut three faces of the cube, so the new solid has three new faces that are equal to the other three. Remember that a cube has six equal faces. So the total surface is the same :)